# Merging two columns (datetime) into one in R

Tags: r

I have a lager data frame with wrong entries in "DyStart" and "DyEnd"....

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwMlE.jpg)

```
ID  DyStart           DyEnd             TmStart     TmEnd
1   04.12.2017        04.12.2017        10:10:00    10:50:00
2   01.12.2017        01.12.2017        12:27:00    16:29:00
3   27.11.2017        27.11.2017        14:31:00    15:08:00
4   07.12.2017 13:26  07.12.2017 13:26
```

I would like to have all dates in column "DyStart" and "DyEnd" and all times in "TmStart" and "TmEnd". I have no problems for the dates...

```
df$DyStart <- format(as.POSIXct(df$Dyformat,format="%d.%m.%Y"),"%d.%m.%Y")
```

But I have trubles with the time. I tried to create a new column and merge with the old column...

```
df$TmStartNew <- format(as.POSIXct(df$DyStart,format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"),"%H:%M:%S")

df$TmStart <- ifelse(is.na(df$TmStart), df$TmStartNew, df$TmStart)
```

I tried diffrent things, but I get always "numeric" or "integer" back and I'm not able to chance the format back to H:M:S

If someone knows the solution I would be very grateful!

Comment: please share a reproducible example using the `dput()`. in the example above, is the 4th entry for time empty/NA??

Comment: Is it correct that you aim is to update "NA" values in `TmStart` and `TmEnd` with values from `DyStart` and `DyEnd` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish it. But I prefer to follow the steps considered in OP to achieve the expected result.

It seems modifications are not performed in the expected order which is causing problems in OP.

Let me explain with the same example used in OP.

```
s <- "ID,  DyStart,           DyEnd,             TmStart,     TmEnd
1,   04.12.2017,        04.12.2017,        10:10:00,    10:50:00
2,   01.12.2017,        01.12.2017,        12:27:00,    16:29:00
3,   27.11.2017,        27.11.2017,        14:31:00,    15:08:00
4,   07.12.2017 13:26,  07.12.2017 13:26"

#Create df as used in OP
df <- read.delim(textConnection(s), header = TRUE, sep = ",", 
strip.white = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#data looks as
> df
  ID          DyStart            DyEnd  TmStart    TmEnd
1  1       04.12.2017       04.12.2017 10:10:00 10:50:00
2  2       01.12.2017       01.12.2017 12:27:00 16:29:00
3  3       27.11.2017       27.11.2017 14:31:00 15:08:00
4  4 07.12.2017 13:26 07.12.2017 13:26

#First create new columns with Time part from corresponding Date column
df$TmStartNew <- format(as.POSIXct(df$DyStart,format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"),"%H:%M:%S")
df$TmEndNew <- format(as.POSIXct(df$DyEnd,format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"),"%H:%M:%S")

#Replace valid values from new columns in original Tm columns
df$TmStart <- ifelse(!is.na(df$TmStartNew), df$TmStartNew, df$TmStart)
df$TmEnd <- ifelse(!is.na(df$TmEndNew), df$TmEndNew, df$TmEnd)

#Now modify Date columns to remove time part
df$DyStart <- format(as.POSIXct(df$DyStart,format="%d.%m.%Y"),"%d.%m.%Y")
df$DyEnd <- format(as.POSIXct(df$DyEnd,format="%d.%m.%Y"),"%d.%m.%Y")

#data frame will now contain
> df
  ID    DyStart      DyEnd  TmStart    TmEnd TmStartNew TmEndNew
1  1 04.12.2017 04.12.2017 10:10:00 10:50:00       <NA>     <NA>
2  2 01.12.2017 01.12.2017 12:27:00 16:29:00       <NA>     <NA>
3  3 27.11.2017 27.11.2017 14:31:00 15:08:00       <NA>     <NA>
4  4 07.12.2017 07.12.2017 13:26:00 13:26:00   13:26:00 13:26:00
```

Once can now drop `TmStartNew` & `TmEndNew` columns.

As mentioned at top this solution has been created in the same line of the OP but there are other ways to achieve the same result.

Comment: @Michele What's the problem?

Comment: Tanks for the help!!! Before replacing the valid values from new columns in origianl Tm colums I had to set the Tm colums as.character and now it works perfect!

Comment: ...sorry, the first comment went away too fast. While I was searching for the problem and wrote a comment I was interrupted. After the first try TmEnd for example looked like this ("10", "44", "41", 13:26:00) instead of ("10:50:00", "16:29:00", "15:08:00", "13:26:00"). Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mutate` from the `dplyr` package to add the new column and `dmy_hms` from the `lubridate` package to convert the strings to datetimes after pasting the dates and times together.

It would look like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(tm_start_new = lubridate::dmy_hms(paste(DyStart, TmStart)),
         tm_end_new = lubridate::dmy_hms(paste(DyEnd, TmEnd)))
```

This would give you this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 7
      ID    DyStart      DyEnd  TmStart    TmEnd        tm_start_new          tm_end_new
  <fctr>     <fctr>     <fctr>   <fctr>   <fctr>              <dttm>              <dttm>
1      1 04.12.2017 04.12.2017 10:10:00 10:50:00 2017-12-04 10:10:00 2017-12-04 10:50:00
2      2 01.12.2017 01.12.2017 12:27:00 16:29:00 2017-12-01 12:27:00 2017-12-01 16:29:00
3      3 27.11.2017 27.11.2017 14:31:00 15:08:00 2017-11-27 14:31:00 2017-11-27 15:08:00
```

**Note:** I converted the dataframe to a tibble so that you can see that the class is actually a datetime object.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an indexes with `grepl` to locate where `DyStart` and `DyEnd` have full dates:

```
i1 <- !grepl('\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}', df$DyStart)
i2 <- !grepl('\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}', df$DyEnd)
```

Then you can replace the other values with correct ones:

```
df$DyStart[i1] <- paste(df$DyStart[i1], df$TmStart[i1])
df$DyEnd[i1] <- paste(df$DyEnd[i1], df$TmEnd[i1])
```

Next, you need to paste `:00` to the other lines:

```
df$DyStart[!i1] <- paste0(df$DyStart[!i1], ':00')
df$DyEnd[!i2] <- paste0(df$DyEnd[!i2], ':00')
```

Now you can transform the column to date-format:

```
df[2:3] <- lapply(df[2:3], function(x) as.POSIXct(x, format = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'))
```

The result:

```
> df
  ID             DyStart               DyEnd  TmStart    TmEnd
1  1 2017-12-04 10:10:00 2017-12-04 10:50:00 10:10:00 10:50:00
2  2 2017-12-01 12:27:00 2017-12-01 16:29:00 12:27:00 16:29:00
3  3 2017-11-27 14:31:00 2017-11-27 15:08:00 14:31:00 15:08:00
4  4 2017-12-07 13:26:00 2017-12-07 13:26:00
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to separate the date and time in the last row of your example in order to convert them into dates and times, you could follow this instance:

Your data is

```
data <- read.table(text=
"'ID' 'DyStart' 'DyEnd' 'TmStart' 'TmEnd'
'1' '04.12.2017' '05.12.2017' '10:10:00' '10:50:00'
'2' '01.12.2017' '01.12.2017' '12:27:00' '16:29:00'
'3' '27.11.2017' '27.11.2017' '14:31:00' '15:08:00'
'4' '07.12.2017 13:26' '07.12.2017 13:26' '' ''", stringsAsFactors=F, header=T)
```

Functions definition and use in order to clean the dates and times:

```
fn_date <- function(columnDate){
columnDate <- ifelse(lapply(strsplit(columnDate, " "), length)==2,
                  unlist(strsplit(columnDate, " ")[lapply(strsplit(columnDate, " "), length)==2])[1],
                  columnDate)
return(columnDate)
}

fn_time <- function(columnDate, columnTime){
columnTime <- ifelse(lapply(strsplit(columnDate, " "), length)==2,
                     paste0(unlist(strsplit(columnDate, " ")[lapply(strsplit(columnDate, " "), length)==2])[2],":00"),
                     columnTime)
return(columnTime)
}

data$TmStart <- fn_time(data$DyStart, data$TmStart)
data$TmEnd <- fn_time(data$DyEnd, data$TmEnd)
data[,2:3] <- lapply(data[,2:3], fn_date)
```

And converting the columns into their designated formats with the help of `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
data[,2:3] <- lapply(data[,2:3], dmy)
data[,4:5] <- lapply(data[,4:5], hms)
```

The result is:

```
  ID    DyStart      DyEnd    TmStart      TmEnd
1  1 2017-12-04 2017-12-05 10H 10M 0S 10H 50M 0S
2  2 2017-12-01 2017-12-01 12H 27M 0S 16H 29M 0S
3  3 2017-11-27 2017-11-27 14H 31M 0S  15H 8M 0S
4  4 2017-12-07 2017-12-07 13H 26M 0S 13H 26M 0S
```

Answer (score 0):

I will write two small functions to use for your problem:

```
 #Function to extract time from the dates and merge it with the time column:
  Extract_Time=function(DATE,TIME){
   where=grep("\\s",DATE)
   DATE[where]=paste0(DATE[where],":00")#Am assuming all the data you have does not contain seconds
   ifelse(is.na(TIME),format(strptime(DATE,'%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'),'%H:%M:%S'),TIME)
 }

 #Function for the date column:
 DATE=function(x)as.Date(x,'%d.%m.%Y')
 transform(dat1,DyStart=DATE(DyStart),
           DyEnd=DATE(DyEnd),
           TmStart=Extract_Time(DyStart,TmStart),
           TmEnd=Extract_Time(DyEnd,TmEnd))

  ID    DyStart      DyEnd  TmStart    TmEnd
1  1 2017-12-04 2017-12-04 10:10:00 10:50:00
2  2 2017-12-01 2017-12-01 12:27:00 16:29:00
3  3 2017-11-27 2017-11-27 14:31:00 15:08:00
4  4 2017-12-07 2017-12-07 13:26:00 13:26:00
5  5 2017-12-08 2017-12-08 15:26:00 16:26:00
```

DATA USED:

```
dat1=read.table(text="ID  DyStart  DyEnd    TmStart  TmEnd
1   04.12.2017        04.12.2017        10:10:00    10:50:00
2   01.12.2017        01.12.2017        12:27:00    16:29:00
3   27.11.2017        27.11.2017        14:31:00    15:08:00
4   '07.12.2017 13:26' '07.12.2017 13:26' NA NA    
5   '08.12.2017 15:26' '08.12.2017 16:26' NA NA    ",h=T,stringsAsFactor=F)
```